# Not understanding why ViewState is not increasing in size when changing content?

Tags: c#, viewstate, asp.net-4.0

I thought I understood ViewState, but this is a bit of a weird one.

I have a page of 1000 labels and textboxes like this:

```
<dt>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1">Label1</asp:Label>
</dt>
<dd>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
</dd>
```

All incremeting by 1. I've added a button to the top:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="PostBack" Text="Post it all back!" OnClick="ChangeValues"/>
```

and the corresponding code is:

```
protected void ChangeValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
   {
      string textBoxId = "TextBox" + i;
      ((TextBox)Page.FindControl(textBoxId)).Text = textBoxId;
   }
}
```

So what I would understand is:

1. First page load, the controls are set up initially, therefore no control viewstate created
2. On postback, the button click is modifying the controls. Therefore, when generating the ViewState, .NET realises that the text has changed from the default and records this in the viewstate.

Now for 1000 controls, you'd expect it to be reasonably big, well bigger than this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjYzODc0MDE1ZGQRGHqYtZTbbkevIfg33I4Wja+xfz0at0+fDMS72BtZNA==" />
```

I think I'm missing a trick here. I have turned on `Trace=true`, and noticed that all of the ViewState is still 0 bytes. `EnableViewState` and `ViewStateMode` are not declared in the `<@Page` directive, so ViewState is on and working.

Can anyone help me understand why I am misunderstanding how this is working?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you could possibly be doing with over 1,000 controls on a web page.

Comment: It was just an extreme example, you can reduce it to 50 if you want - or 2. It still happens.

Comment: Whew, I'm relieved to hear that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's because the Text property of a TextBox doesn't need to be saved to ViewState as it will be rendered to the page and posted back with the post data.

If you look at the implementation of `TextBox` with Reflector you'll see it has a property `SaveTextViewState` that controls whether the Text property needs to be saved to ViewState:

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    if (!this.SaveTextViewState)
    {
        // This means the Text property will not be saved to ViewState
        this.ViewState.SetItemDirty("Text", false);
    }
    return base.SaveViewState();
}
```

In cases where saving the ViewState is necessary (e.g. the TextBox is not Visible), `SaveTextViewState` returns true and the Text property is saved to ViewState.

**UPDATE**

According to Reflector the implementation of the `SaveTextViewState` property (the property used to determine whether `Text` needs to be persisted to ViewState) is as follows:

```
private bool SaveTextViewState
{
    get
        {
            if (this.TextMode == TextBoxMode.Password) return false;
        }
        if (((base.Events[EventTextChanged] == null) && 
              base.IsEnabled) && 
              ((this.Visible && !this.ReadOnly)  && 
              (base.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I.e. `Text` is persisted to ViewState if it's not a password textbox and any of the following are true:

- there exists a handler for the TextChanged event (in this case it needs the original value to detect if the text has changed)
- the control is disabled (in which case the Text won't be posted back)
- the control is not visible (in which case it won't be rendered)
- the control is readonly (Text won't be posted back)
- the control type is not `TextBox` (don't optimize by suppressing ViewState as this may impact the implementation of a derived control).

Essentially an optimization that suppresses ViewState if it's sure it won't be needed.

Comment: I would expect it to be in the ViewState, as it has changed between LoadPostbackData() and SavePostBackData(). Although the Request.Form has the information, how would it determine if the content has changed the next time around?

Comment: Thanks Joe, your updated explanation has helped. I believe that since I am not explicitly looking for a changed event, the API does not inform me of the change by not storing it in the ViewState.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Controls which implement `IPostBackEventHandler` like `Textbox, Checkbox`, etc. will retain the state `even after disabling the viewstate`. The reason is during the Load Postback Data stage, these controls will get state information from Posted back form.

But controls like label which do not implement IPostBackEventHandler will not get any state information from posted back data and hence depend entirely on viewstate to maintain the state.

Comment: I can understand why the Label text isn't in the ViewState as it isn't changing from the originally rendered content. But if you compare the TextBox items - on initialisation it is blank. On transmission to the user it has content, modified from the original blank state. In order to determine a OnTextChanged event, it must be able to compare the data sent to the user (from ViewState) with the next posted (Request.Form) value?

Comment: @Dominic - "In order to determine a OnTextChanged event, it must be able to compare the data sent to the user (from ViewState)" - if you have a TextChanged event handler, it will persist the Text property to ViewState.  See my updated answer.